# Python, index, and dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and have a question about indexes and data frames.  I have a 3 source files that can be uniquely identified with three keys (district_code, district_name, district_type).  I'm validating data between the source files and what is in the database.  The code below only finds matching dist_name and dist_code betweeen source file and database and then matches one with the other depending on which value is available.  I need to add another condition to the function adding an additional index/key (district_type) that will make the dist unique matching and comparing all three keys.

* Edit**
To simplify this I changed the logic in my approach.  By concatenating the two keys district_code and district_type I have a unique identifier (dist_key).  I changed the function below to reflect this change but I'm receiving a **"keyError: u'no item named dist_key"**.  This is function is producing an error because I believe the new unique identifier is only defined in this function.  Being a newbee to this language and scripting, I'm unsure of how to call the needed variable (dist_key) outside the function.

```
if dfyearfound:
    df2['district_name']=df2['district_name'].str.strip()
    df2['district_code']=df2['district_code'].str.strip()
    **df2['dist_key']=df2['dist_key'].str.strip()**  """This line is causing the error"""

def addNamesCodes(testframe,districtnamedata,districtcodedata):
        """ Function that will correct any missing data such as district names or district codes.  Parameter is a pandas dataframe, dictionaries which map the district names and district codes """


        #contain list of correct district codes and district names
        districtnames=[]
        districtkeys=[]
        #Non matches
        fdistrictnames=[]
        fdistrictkeys=[]
        #fill empty values in names and codes

        testframe['district_name']=testframe['district_name'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
        testframe['district_name']=testframe['district_name'].fillna('')
        testframe['district_code']=testframe['district_code'].fillna('')
        testframe['dist_key']=testframe['dist_key'].fillna('')
        testframe['dist_key']=testframe['dist_key']+testframe['district_code']
        #Create two new columns containing the district names and district codes in same format as enrollment and teacher data  
        for i in range(len(testframe.index)):
            #both district code and district name are present
            if districtnamedata.has_key(testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]) and districtcodedata.has_key(testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]):
                #district code and district name are a match
                if ((districtnamedata[testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]]==testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]) and (districtcodedata[testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]]==testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]])):
                    districtnames.append(districtnamedata[testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]])
                    districtkeys.append(districtcodedata[testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]])
                #potential wrong mappings
                else:
                    districtkeys.append(testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]])
                    districtnames.append(districtnamedata[testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]])
            else:
                #check if district code is present
                if districtnamedata.has_key(testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]):
                    districtkeys.append(testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]])
                    districtnames.append(districtnamedata[testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]]])
                #check if only district name is present 
                elif districtcodedata.has_key(testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]):
                    districtnames.append(testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]])
                    districtkeys.append(districtcodedata[testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]]])
                #complete nonmatches
                else:
                    fdistrictnames.append(testframe['district_name'][testframe.index[i]])
                    fdistrictkeys.append(testframe['dist_key'][testframe.index[i]])
        #extend the list by the complete nonmatches
        districtnames.extend(fdistrictnames)
        districtkeys.extend(fdistrictkeys)

        return districtnames,districtkeys
```

Sample Source:
Enroll---

```
district_code   district_name   district_type_code  enroll_totals
1                 AITKIN               1                    122
1                 AITKIN               1                    123
1                 SAVAGE               3                    140
1                 SAVAGE               3                    780
15              ST. FRANCIS            1                    782
16              SPRING LAKE            1                    784
```

Finance---

```
district_code   district_name   district_type_code          budget
1                 AITKIN               1                    122000
1                 AITKIN               1                    120003
1                 SAVAGE               3                    140000
1                 SAVAGE               3                    780000
15              ST. FRANCIS            1                    782000
16              SPRING LAKE            1                    784000
```

Teacher---

```
district_code   district_name   district_type_code         Salary
1                 AITKIN               1                    50000
1                 AITKIN               1                    42000
1                 SAVAGE               3                    89000
1                 SAVAGE               3                    32000
15              ST. FRANCIS            1                    78000
16              SPRING LAKE            1                    58000
```

Comment: this code is impossible to run without your data. any chance you could add it?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot given the privacy of the data

Comment: well then please make something up. really can't help you otherwise http://sscce.org/

Comment: the for loop is the part I'm having trouble with.  Where if there is a distname look for dist_code and vice versa.  I was unsure how to add a third condition to handle dist_type

Comment: Part of using `pandas` is using vectorized ops to avoid for loops.  As Paul says, though, without an SSCCE it's a bit of a headache; with one, you'd probably have an answer by now. :^)  You can always replace the source data with equivalent random data.

Comment: If you replace those screenshots with short _typed_ samples, we can copy/paste the data try out your code.

Comment: along the lines with what @DanAllan is saying, here's an example of how to do that (see the question, not necessarily the answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels