# Pandas group by adds index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code, which aims at dividing a column by its grouped mean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : np.random.randn(n)})
df.set_index('expenditure', inplace=True)
test = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['coef'] / x.coef.mean())
```

I like this structure of data before `apply`ing, before I am usually able to just `df['someNewColumn'] = df.apply(...)`. But strangely, this time, I'm not able to instantly remerge the results.

`test` should be indexed by the indices that the `groupby` happened, `expenditure`. However, it has a double index:

```
>>> test
expenditure  expenditure
bar          bar           -0.491900
             bar           -9.332964
             bar            8.019472
             bar           -4.540905
             bar            5.627947
             bar           -0.171765
             bar            5.698813
             bar            6.476207
             bar            8.796249
             bar           -8.284087
             bar            1.426311
             bar           -1.223377
foo          foo            1.900897
             foo            7.057078
             foo            0.060856
             foo            3.850323
             foo            2.928085
             foo           -3.249857
             foo            3.176616
             foo           -1.433766
             foo            0.910017
             foo            1.395376
             foo            1.898315
             foo           -1.903462
             foo           -3.590479
Name: coef, dtype: float64
```

Why does it have a double index and how can I get my normalized column?

```
>>> test.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'foo'], [u'bar', u'foo']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
           names=[u'expenditure', u'expenditure'])
```

My `pandas` version is `0.15.0`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me which version of pandas you're using, but your apply does not work for me at all.

I have trouble with grouping on the index. So I always dump the index and group on a normal column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : np.random.randn(n)})
```

then you can do either:

```
df.groupby('expenditure').coef.apply(lambda x: x / x.mean())
```

or the following which is almost exactly what you tried before

```
df.groupby('expenditure').apply(lambda x: x.coef / x.coef.mean())
```

Comment: Functions applied to `groupby` objects see the whole group (a dataframe or series). The main problem here is that the lambda does not return a single value, but a series instead. I agree with your proposed solution, but maybe the last bit should be `df.coef.mean(level='expenditure')`.

Comment: whoops. You are correct. I read his code too quickly and didn't notice the apply was on the grouped data. I'll fix my comments above.

Comment: Also, using the `.div` method will broadcast results based on the index: `test = df['coef'].div(df['coef'].mean(level='expenditure'))`

Comment: i think the issue is doing groupby on the index.

Comment: you can group by the index just fine, the issue is you're still returning series object and stuffing them in a series with an index   of `['foo', 'bar']`. If the OP wants to normalize the `coef` column based on the mean of the groups, the solution will be a little more nuanced. I think the solution in my previous comment achieves this.

Comment: `.div`, `.mul`, etc are elusive, but very powerful. Here's where I first learned about them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if that helps you, but since you've indexed the column `expenditure`, you need to groupby this index before applying to achieve what I believe you want, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : np.random.randn(n)})

df.set_index('expenditure', inplace=True)

# when you try to apply, you need to groupby 'expenditure' -- which is the df.index
test = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x['coef'] /x.coef.mean())

test

expenditure
bar            expenditure
bar            2.013101
bar       ...
foo            expenditure
foo            1
Name: coef, dtype...
dtype: object

test.index
Index([u'bar', u'foo'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Copypasted the wrong code, sorry. Updated the question. Im doing almost the same, but I group by `level=0`, which is the same. Yet I get the output for `test` that I listed above. Its not exactly clear how your output looks like, due to the `...`. Is it similar to mine? If not, which version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: @FooBar, `level=0` will give the same result as above as you have only 1 index by the time you do the `apply`. the **...** is exactly from the output as you're trying to apply the `.../x.coef.mean()` on a group level. However, I think JD Long's suggestion is more likely what you're trying to achieve. And my pandas's version is **0.14.1**

Answer (score 0):

Let's make your dataframe a little simpler for illustration purposes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = 10
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
        'coef' : np.arange(n)
    }, 
    index=pd.Index(np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n), name='expenditure'),
)
df


             coef groupid
expenditure              
bar             0     one
foo             1     two
foo             2     two
bar             3     one
foo             4     two
foo             5     two
foo             6     two
foo             7     two
foo             8     two
bar             9     two
```

You can compute the mean `coef` for each `expenditure` group using two different methods:

```
means = df['coef'].mean(level='expenditure')
```

or

```
means = df['coef'].groupby(level='expenditure').mean()
```

Both give me:

```
expenditure
bar            4.000000
foo            4.714286
Name: coef, dtype: float64
```

So then we can divide the `coef` column by the grouped means and broadcast that against the `expenditure` values:

```
test = df['coef'].div(means, level='expenditure')
test

expenditure
bar            0.000000
bar            0.750000
bar            2.250000
foo            0.212121
foo            0.424242
foo            0.848485
foo            1.060606
foo            1.272727
foo            1.484848
foo            1.696970
Name: coef, dtype: float64
```

Our original values in the `bar` group are 0, 3, and 9, so results of 0.0, 0.75, 2.25 check out.