# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

my inputs are, data input at top

```
Date        Time    Open    High    Low    Close    Volume
02/01/2015  14:30   79.52   79.73   79.52   79.71   10841
02/01/2015  14:31   79.6999 79.6999 79.61   79.67   1426
02/01/2015  14:32   79.69   79.7    79.69   79.7    800
02/01/2015  14:33   79.7    79.759  79.7    79.759  1158
02/01/2015  14:34   79.747  79.747  79.73   79.73   1125
02/01/2015  14:35   79.73   79.73   79.71   79.71   301
02/01/2015  14:36   79.8    79.82   79.75   79.82   7818
02/01/2015  14:37   79.82   79.83   79.778  79.82   6985
02/01/2015  14:38   79.8099 79.8099 79.72   79.72   1026
02/01/2015  14:39   79.77   79.78   79.7396 79.78   870
02/01/2015  14:40   79.79   79.79   79.73   79.73   12031
02/01/2015  14:41   79.76   79.76   79.6901 79.736  4642
02/01/2015  14:42   79.7301 79.744  79.7301 79.744  1099


numRow = 1
endRow = 50
dHaGreen0 = {}
for ticker in Index_tickers.ticker:
    index_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\me\\Dropbox\\MktData\\Index_list\\' +     ticker + '_' + str(timeFrame) + '.csv')
    open0 = index_data.Open
    close0 = index_data.Close
    high0 = index_data.High
    low0 = index_data.Low
    dHaClose0 = (open0 + high0 + low0 + close0) / 4 
    dHaOpen0 = (dHaClose1 + dHaOpen1) / 2
    dHaGreen0 = dHaClose0 >= dHaOpen0

        if numRow < endRow:
            dOpen0 = index_data.ix[numRow, index_data.Open]

            if dHaGreen0 == True & dHaGreen1 == True:
                dPosition = "Long"
            numRow = numRow + 1
```

when I print dHaGreen0, it returns a list of bool, and "dtype: bool". But when I go to use dHaGreen0 in the if statement , I get the error ValueError:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have checked many of the suggested answers from previous questions but can't get read across. All responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're looking at the entire arrays when it seems like you want to look at single elements. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I want to check each row as I go through the loop. I have the loop 
 
        
        if dHaGreen0 == True & dHaGreen1 == True:
              dEntryPx = close0
        numRow = numRow + 1

Comment: i can't read that comment at all. if the info is relevant to the question, the add it there. as it stands now, you're example produces a lot of errors when I try to run it in a fresh interpreter. you example should be self-contained and immediately runable by people like me.

Comment: HI Paul, I have added my loop detail to the initial question, apologies for confusion. I would like to check dHaGreen0 on each line of loop as I scroll through..

Comment: Sweet, but you understand how I can't run that without your file, right? Your script should generate the data it needs to run. Also, your indentation is broken.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your patience, I believe I have corrected the question and given all the necessary data ( which I understand is helpful !!)

Comment: your indentation is still wrong and you're still referencing a file that only you have. you should use `StringIO` to mock your datafile. see here for an old (python 2) example of how to do that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels)

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is correct. dHaGreen0 is an array of bool values. When you ask "dHaGreen0 == True", you need to decide on one of the two following interpretations:

Do you mean if *any* value is dHaGreen0 is True? If so, replace "dHaGreen0 == True" with "any(dHaGreen0) == True".

Or do you mean if *all* values in dHaGreen0 are True? If so, replace "dHaGreen0 == True" with "all(dHaGreen0) == True".

Similarly for dHaGreen1

If you're trying to do this for each pair:

```
dPosition = dHaGreen0 & dHaGreen1
```

This will then give you an array of booleans giving the result for each pair.

Comment: Hi Chad, I have added more detail to my initial question. I would like to check dHaGreen0 for each line of code as I loop through..