# 'if' on a function when calculating a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with 2 columns: `date1` and `date2`. I want to calculate a new one with the months distances between the 2.

If I do:

```
def meses(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year)*12 + d1.month - d2.month

df['mora']=meses(df.date1.dt,df.date2.dt)
```

works ok, but if I want to subtract one month on the cases where the difference in days of the 2 dates are negative as follows:

```
def meses(d1, d2):
    if (d2.day-d1.day)<0:
        resto=1
    else:
        resto=0
    return (d1.year - d2.year)*12 + d1.month - d2.month - resto

df['mora']=meses(df.date1.dt,df.date2.dt)
```

gives me the following error:

> ----> 2     if (d2.day-d1.day)<0:
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

It seems that the problem is with the `if` in the function. How can I solve it?

---

My dataframe:

```
date1   date2
2013-08-27  2013-11-07
2013-10-01  2013-12-06
2013-11-01  2014-01-09
2013-11-29  2014-02-05
2013-12-27  2014-03-17
2014-01-31  2014-04-24
```

I want a new column 'mora' with the difference on months of the other 2 columns, the first function gives me:

```
df['mora']=meses(df.date2.dt,df.date1.dt)

    date1   date2   mora
2013-08-27  2013-11-07  3
2013-10-01  2013-12-06  2
2013-11-01  2014-01-09  2
2013-11-29  2014-02-05  3
2013-12-27  2014-03-17  3
2014-01-31  2014-04-24  3
```

but if I use the `.day` version it gives me the error.

Comment: You should provide a reproductible example. Here, input data is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one works because you are performing a simple calculation on an entire series at once i.e. just subtracting or adding the entire column. The second one doesn't work because you checking to see if an entire series/list of values is less than another. Obviously more efficient ways to do this but I keeping as close to your original solution as possible, try this instead:

```
import numpy as np

df['mora']=np.where(df.date1.dt.day < df.date2.dt.day, \
         (df.date1.dt.year - df.date2.dt.year)*12 + df.date1.dt.month - df.date2.dt.month - 1, \
          (df.date1.dt.year - df.date2.dt.year)*12 + df.date1.dt.month - df.date2.dt.month)
```

Comment: Thanks! works, but how would you do it more efficiently?

Comment: `df['mora']=(df.date1-df.date2).apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))`    followed by `df['mora']=np.where(df.mora<0, df.mora-1, df.mora)` .   You may have to use `(df.date1.day-df.date2.day).apply...`, not sure what your formatting is currently.

Answer (score 0):

The message provided by the `ValueError` is clear:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The `if` clause get the truth value of series `d2.day-d1.day`, which is a `Series` itself.
If you want `all` row to be `< 0`, then you should use the `all` keyword.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699265/3077939)