# Trying to code a binary variable based on a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

Having an issue coding up a binary variable based on the code below.  I'd like the variable `metric` to be 1 if `feature` is less or equal to 30 and 0 otherwise. When I run this code I get the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
if df1.Feature <= 30:
    df1.metric=1
else:
    df1.metric=0
```

Comment: I guess the error code line is not posted. I can't see `a` variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699034/the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any)

Comment: This confuses me as well, there is no a object at all, I have imported my libraries (numpy/pandas) and the data and attempted to create the variable REC30PY

Comment: If by "binary variable" you mean a boolean, consider using the `bool` values `True` and `False` instead of the integers 1 and 0. I don't think this is directly relevant to your error message, but it's a little cleaner of a design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing the truth value of an entire Series as one object.  You can use `np.where` instead to test each element.  In your case:

```
df1.loc[:, 'REC30PY'] = np.where(df1.velocity<=30, 1, 0)
```

Or, to get booleans:

```
df1.loc[:, 'REC30PY'] = np.where(df1.velocity<=30, True, False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert boolean mask `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1['REC30PY'] = (df1.velocity<=30).astype(int)
```

And for `True` with `False`s:

```
df1['REC30PY'] = df1.velocity<=30
```