# How does the `level` parameter work for pandas add method

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen the `level` parameter for the `pd.DataFrame` methods `add`, `sub`, `div`, and `mul`.  [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) states:

> level : int or name
>
> Broadcast across a level, matching Index values on the passed MultiIndex level

I can't seem to understand how this is used appropriately.

Consider:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['one', 'two']]),
                  list('ab'))

df

       a  b
A one  0  1
  two  2  3
B one  4  5
  two  6  7
```

If I add 100, I get what I expected.  The `level` parameter has no relevance.

```
pd.concat([df, df.add(100), df.add(100, level=0), df.add(100, level=1)],
          axis=1, keys=['Original', 'No Level', 'Level 0', 'Level 1'])


      Original    No Level      Level 0      Level 1     
             a  b        a    b       a    b       a    b
A one        0  1      100  101     100  101     100  101
  two        2  3      102  103     102  103     102  103
B one        4  5      104  105     104  105     104  105
  two        6  7      106  107     106  107     106  107
```

But I thought adding an array would be distinctive.

```
a = np.arange(2) + 100

pd.concat([df, df.add(a), df.add(a, level=0), df.add(a, level=1)],
          axis=1, keys=['Original', 'No Level', 'Level 0', 'Level 1'])

      Original    No Level      Level 0      Level 1     
             a  b        a    b       a    b       a    b
A one        0  1      100  102     100  102     100  102
  two        2  3      102  104     102  104     102  104
B one        4  5      104  106     104  106     104  106
  two        6  7      106  108     106  108     106  108
```

`level` made no difference.

I expected something like:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.add(a, axis=0))

         a    b
A one  100  101
  two  103  104
B one  104  105
  two  107  108
```

Can someone give a concrete example on how and when to use this parameter?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels) may help you.

Comment: @piRSquared - ya, good idea.